# How to improve slow app startup in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, performance, xamarin, xamarin.forms, startup

I've been trying to improve the app startup time of my app without any success. I'm using MvvmCross, but based on my logs, the slowdowns seem to occur before it even gets to the MvvmCross initialization part. Once it gets there, it seems to be quite fast. I even tried removing all my initialization code, yet that did not make any difference to the slow startup.

Based on log, I can see that time is lost when libraries/plugins are being imported and I have no idea how to improve this. I tried linking everything, but I didn't gain much in startup speed. The only significant speed up was after using AOT compiling, but that results in ridiculously large .apk with an even bigger install size of ~200-300mb, which is unacceptable.

I need help on improving the app startup time without compromising the application size.

Comment: I have several plugins added. it takes ~ 15 secs.

Comment: And a desired or acceptable time for you is...?

Comment: Maximum ~ 5 sec

Comment: It must be obvious, but have you seen [this article](https://blog.xamarin.com/5-ways-boost-xamarin-forms-app-startup-time/)? Especially the points #3 and #5. About the plugins (Note on the tip #5), if you're using open sources plugins (and it's license allows), you can think about import to your solution only the functionalities you're actually using, or even build a custom package with just this ones.

Comment: ~5 sec, is improbable, I think. It's commonly the _nude_ app starting time. Have you thought about to move to Xamarin _<Platform>_ approach or change to `Shared` sharing strategy (I'm not sure it'll make a real difference on startup time, but it should do in the app size to use the AOT workaround)?

Comment: Are you using image as background & its large size?

Comment: @RanjithKumar, No, I am not using image as background. However my app contains images for other purposes such as icons

Comment: @SelvarathinamVinoch Incase if you use the large size images move to drawable-nodpi folder(If not there create it & move). Use this online tool to reduce image size https://kraken.io/web-interface

Comment: The more assemblies your app contains the more has Xamarin.Forms to scan for custom renderers and such. You can improve startup time by minimizing your assembly count.

Comment: I use a set of custom msbuild Tasks that combines libraries, after Linking, in a master library via assembly-based modules, etc... The startup times were greatly improved but it is a pain to setup and I currently have no docs for it (I did it for a client that eventually re-wrote the app in Java to avoid the problem which of course it did...) There is work being done by the Xamarin.Android group to improve startup times as it is really bad on a lot of devices, but I am unsure of any release/date that they are targeting.